# Why is my vertical monitor's viewport much smaller than it should be?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two 1920 x 1080 monitors, one horizontal and one vertical. When visiting [this viewport measuring site](https://viewportsizes.com/mine/) on on my horizontal one it says 1920 × 947 which is normal. On my vertical one though it says `864 x 1403`.

The viewport width is over 200 pixels smaller than it should be! I see no visual clue that could explain such a weird phenomenon: Chrome window correctly fills the screen, the web pages are complete, etc.

Below is a screenshot taken [from another site that measures viewport width](http://matanich.com/test/viewport-width/) that shows both the viewport width (847px) calculated by that particular website, *and* the actual width of the screen as indicated by my screenshot app (1058px).

This looks like black magic. If anybody has the slightest clue please come forward!

[image: Screenshot of my monitor.]

Comment: The viewport being measured is the window size of the browser window you open that site with. Check you are full-screened or at least maximised. It also, I just realised in testing, resizes live. Fullscreen, I get 2560x1440, which is correct. Windowed, I get whatever I drag it to, again appears to be correct.

Comment: Yes the problem occurs when my browser is full-screen and maximised.

Comment: @drake035 – did you try another browser?

Comment: Just tried, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1080 / 864 = 1.25, so you're likely to have a 25% zoom-in somewhere. Try doing this: ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/windows-10-2nd-monitor-resolution-zoomed-in/66f572a0-c916-4db1-9a2d-ae50d2a2a50e))

> Go to your desktop (Windows Key + D), right click your desktop background and select 'Display settings'. You will see a bar that says 'Change the size of text, app and other items: 125%' or something to that effect. Move the slider left until it says 100% then hit apply. You will need to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Gosh you were right, I had my vertical monitor with a 125% setting applied! No idea how it got there. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It's been my experience that Windows 10 defaults to a zoom factor of 125% or 150% for HD monitors and 300% for 4K monitors.  I find myself having to set these the way I want them every time I attach a new display/projector to the computer for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

https://viewportsizes.com/mine/ gave me very weird results on both Firefox and Chrome,
for both modes of full-screen or not.

If you go to their home page, you can see that the last recorded viewport
setting dates to 2013-05, meaning that nobody has bothered with this website
for the last six years!

I suggest not worrying about it - their JavaScript is theirs to fix,
although it doesn't seem like this website is still being maintained.

Comment: https://viewportsizes.com/mine/ is just an example I found seconds before posting this question, in order to illustrate it. The problem occurs on any website unfortunately. The viewport is just drastically reduced across browser on my vertical monitor, for no apparent reason.

Comment: You would need to give a better example for better analysis of the problem (although I find it hard to believe that such a problem exists if the JavaScript is correct and up to the latest standards).

Comment: A bette test is http://matanich.com/test/viewport-width/

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with a screenshot. This is absolutely incomprehensible.

Comment: Press F11 while in the browser to make it full-screen.

Comment: Doesn't change the viewport value.

Comment: This is weird. Have you tried in more browsers? In Chrome Incognito mode or Firefox Safe mode?